# connecting to mqtt broker (mosquitto) installed on raspberry pi over internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed Mosquitto on raspberry pi B+ and everything is working on LAN,just by using its local IP I am able to connect clients to broker. Now I want the clients to be able to connect to broker over internet, any idea how to do it?
I

Answer (score 0):

You really need to supply a LOT more information here to get a definitive answer.

But I'm going to assume a basic home broadband set up.

You need to enable port forwarding in your router to forward port 1883 to the raspberry pi. How you do this will depend on which brand of router you have.

You will also need either a static IP address for your home broadband or dynamic DNS setup so what ever you want to connect to your broker can find it.

You probably also want to ensure that the IP address given to your raspberry pi by your router doesn't change or you will have to change the port forwarding settings every time that happens.

Comment: thanks for your response, I did kind of tried port forwarding but it generates lots of security issues with it and I am not that well versed to figure out a way. I am looking for something besides port forwarding or VPN